# What dot matrix printer? - UK, 1987

Tags: identify-this-peripheral, font

I worked in publishing in the UK and am trying to identify a dot matrix printer from 1987. I have binders full of printouts from this printer. I think I've identified that it is a 9-pin dot matrix printer. It had the ability of printing a more condensed version as well, as some of my printouts are more condensed. It was connected to a BBC Micro computer.

I am making a font to match the wider printout because I can't find one that is accurate to this particular model. (Most fonts assume that the horizontal dots are spaced the same as the vertical dots, but with this printer, the dots are spaced a tiny bit wider horizontally, like the top of the n, or the crossbar of the H, etc.)

I have analyzed the font extensively and am almost done with the GlyphsApp font. But I would like to know the printer brand! I assumed it was an Epson, but I can't find an image that matches.

I will attach images - one that I took in the office where I worked that shows the printer with 3 dark gray buttons. The other two are of printouts, wide and condensed.

EDIT Nov 22: Added 3 photos of the font in progress, including the M overlaid on the very helpful "Ideal M" from Comment.

[image: dot matrix printer connected to BBC Micro]

[image: dot matrix sample printout scan wide font]
[image: dot matrix sample printout scan condensed font]
[image: example of the capital Q]

[image: SQ-80 font overlaid on printout]

[image: Q fixed]

[image: M in Glyphs]

[image: Font M pink overlaid on Ideal M]

[image: Grid in After Effects with font overlay]

Comment: Normal 9-pin printers used 120dpi horizontally and 72dpi vertically in normal 80-column mode, with a constraint that no dot could be horizontally adjacent to another.  In emphasized mode which took twice as long to print, every dot had a second dot printed one column to its right.  In condensed mode, resolution was increased to 240dpi, but two extra blank columns were added between characters.  The lettering looks typical of such printers, but I don't have a font reference handy to see if any letter forms are unusual.  The printout does not have the "Q" shape used by the Star Gemini 10x, ...

Comment: Looks much like a CTI CP-80 - but not the Model II

Comment: ... and the X doesn't match my memory of what most printers would have used, but the "0" and "D" are pixel perfect to what I remember.

Comment: @supercat - I added another image of a capital Q, if that's of interest. I have a year's worth of printouts (3 binders full) and this is the only Q I could find!

Comment: @QuinGold: The Q definitely doesn't match that of the Star Gemini 10x as shown on page 239 of https://minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/Star%20Micronics/dot_matrix/Star%20Micronics%20-%20Gemini-10X%20and%20Gemini-15X%20-%20Users%20Manual.pdf [which is labeled page 233] nor the MX-80 https://mirrors.apple2.org.za/ftp.apple.asimov.net/documentation/hardware/printers/Epson%20MX-80%20Printer%20Manual.pdf (the S matches the Gemini but not the Epson).  I find it interesting how many 9-pin printers have slight differences in their fonts.

Comment: Have you looked at EffectsEighty - https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/effects-eighty/ ? It uses matrices taken from the Epson manual.

Comment: Wow! Epson has drivers for the MX-80 for Windows 10! Which is pretty cool because I remember years ago (Windows 8?) that HP had started to drop drivers (i.e., not update them) for some older printers. https://epson.com/Support/Printers/Impact-Printers/MX-Series/Epson-MX-80/s/SPT_M80#drivers

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact They are impact printers, and are still used for certain legal purposes where a copy must be made at the same time as the original (using multipart stationery).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm not disputing the benefits of using them. But they are rather old. Arguably anyone using them should have replaced them 20 or 30 years ago with a more recent Epson or Okidata. Okidata 320 series still has a *lot* of traction in POS that needs more than 2" thermal paper. For my own customers it was ~ 15 - 20 years ago that I migrated to "just print two copies of everything on a laser printer", which is quite common now (e.g., auto service, medical, etc.) - customer signs one and hands it back, and keeps the other for their records.

Comment: I do have a wider printer, guess it can print 132 per line. WordPerfect 5•1 for DOS can show 132 across the screen if right graphics card, then print it.

Comment: The purple SQ matches the Star Gemini 10x font, but not the earlier sample you posted.

Comment: @supercat The purple SQ-80 is my font overlaid on the earlier scan of the printout (the image just above it). I thought it was rather close. Why do you say it doesn't match?
Thanks for the link to the Star Micronics manual with the grid of characters. I wish I had that weeks ago as it would have been easier than squinting at scans! I can only assume that I had set the printer to print a little wider than the regular font, as the horizontal dots have more space than the vertical dots. I used to have to proofread these pages, so maybe I found it easier on the eyes.

Comment: @QuinGold: Second row from the bottom has two dots in the original, one each on the left and right sides.  You added a second dot which is present on the SG-10x (but which as an owner of the printer I thought was ugly), but not on the sample you posted.

Comment: Oops! Good catch!! I forgot to delete that dot. Too focused on the diagonal dots.

Answer (score 15):

The printer looks quite like a C.T.I. CP-80 variant. The silver oval is a give away. See this picture of a CP-80 Model II I have pulled out a few weeks ago for a PC-XT setup to help with [GlaBIOS](https://glabios.org/).

[image]
*(picture mine)*

These printers were sold under various "brands" (Shinwa, Computer Mate, ...) from the mid 1980s on. Essentially cheap rip off of Epson printers. There were at least 5 different models over the years.

Here's an add for the Model 2 from a British magazine, mentioning the BBC as well:

[image]

*(Taken from an [ebay sale](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/300681863654))*

> Most fonts assume that the horizontal dots are spaced the same as the vertical dots, but with this printer, the dots are spaced a tiny bit wider horizontally, [...]

Well, that's the usual issue with recreated fronts as they build an idealized version that never was. Also, width is something that did vary always a bit as it relies on head movement which may differ over time and condidion.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. I could imagine it being a "clone" as the publisher was, let's say, "frugal"... :) "Computer Mate" rings a very distant bell too. 

Interesting that the width could be just a bit wider for the clone. Do I take it that in the real CP-80 the horizontal dot placement was exactly the same spacing as the vertical dot placement?

Comment: Another question: The paper plays a large part in how big the dot appears (i.e., how much it bleeds). How big would the dot have been if the paper had no bleed? I am using a 100 x 100 unit square in Glyphs 3, and have made the master dot 90x90. But I can edit this size and it will affect every dot in the font.

Comment: https://paleotronic.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/printefeature1983-42-copy-2.jpg

This capital A glyph is from an article and it also has more horizontal spacing. Could this have been a "style", as in a Wide or Expanded style of a Regular font? Maybe that explains why all the fonts I have found so far are for a Regular width font and just don't look quite right.

Comment: The basic charset was 9x9 and please, do not expect any details past that it could do 80 characters in standard mode and maybe ~130 condensed. It's fruitless to apply today's features and detailed control with reality (and expectations) back then. Just look at the Ad and notice that it doesn't name any character or line spacing at all. Having 80 chars in ONE line is already the main achievement. And "true decenders" !!!!! Not to mention that the whole text is of course caps only :)) No offence, but it feels as if you're trying to recreate something better than new :)

Comment: @QuinGold In this class "styles" are an euphemism for printing the dos a bit wider or closer. Also don't forget that firing was in large a analogue process, meaning that a horizontal line of dots nay not be a straight die slightly different voltage/induction of the coil. Even worse, timing may vary depending on number of dots firing in the same column, shifting the whole column a bit and so on. I know, hard to believe for anyone custom to today's precision. Also an example why a professional printer back then was three or four times more expensive than above CP-80.

Comment: Understood. I was the production manager and have spent the past few decades working with typography and calligraphy, and it's the simplicity of this dot matrix printout that I am most enamored with. I'm just trying to understand where the extra width is coming from.

Comment: @QuinGold From the timing relation between head firing and head movement. The detail you just added shows perfectly that these printers did not deliver a great repetitive operation. It's random how hard a pin hits and at the same time when. Having random offsets from the desired point to the one produced of less than 1/3rd of a position was a good result. How bad mechanics were (by today's) standard even on high end printers is shown by them operating in high quality mode only in one direction, so errors due movement regularities are mostly the same in all liens :))

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. This is for a handmade art book. I will print templates a few inches high, then using a light table, I can make the dots using calligraphy tools on the art paper on top. The dots I make will be a little "off" so that will mimic the printheads. I had to create a font as it was too difficult to remember the locations of all the dots! 
Some day I hope to have time to make a variation of my clean font, where the dots are all a little "off". I prefer the "dirty typewriter" fonts over the clean ones, so having a "wonky dot matrix" font makes sense to me.

Comment: @QuinGold The whole point is to produce something that comes around to roughly 10 CPI for standard 80 char per line font, adding up to 8 inch width or 12 CPI for 132 characters which again adds up to 8". So if a character is made from a 9x9 cell, then those 8" contain 80x9=720 dots, with a dot being ~1/90" wide. This value is handled by the movement of the head  - and how exact the transport works. Dot distance vertical in turn is fixed by the head - which usually is more exact. And all of that gets twisted by various random input - not to mention wear.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Most 9-pin printers following in the footsteps of the MX-80 used carriage-control motors with feedback that were quite precise.  Backlash may cause text that was printed left-to-right to be slightly misaligned compared with text that was printed right-to-left, but the average pixel spacing was precisely 120x72dpi in normal mode, or 240x72dpi in condensed.

Comment: 8×12=96, the 132 I think is for paper the other way around? Was wondering if font can be copied from ROM, as I'd Epson 870 which includes Cyrillic.

Comment: @AndrewHodson No, to print "the other way around" you needed software that would turn the whole page into a bitmap, rotate and print Sideways (which was a popular program that did that 30 years ago, but I can't find a reference at the moment). 8 x 16.5 = 132. There were some variants - e.g., the Teletype 43 (I had one) used 8-1/2x11 fanfold paper landscape orientation, 12cpi (fixed - not adjustable pitch even though it was a dot-matrix of similar vintage to the MX-80, etc.) could print (I don't remember exactly) 128 or 132 columns. Which makes me think it was probably slightly more than 12 cpi

Comment: but I don't feel like hunting for 35-year-old printouts right now.

Comment: @AndrewHodson - yes, font data can be extracted from ROM data. It's not trivial, though. Character data (at least in the ROMs I've looked at) tends to be stored in a format similar to the "[Esc &](https://archive.org/details/manuallib-id-2606322/page/n90/mode/1up)" command. This includes character width data, so the very determined retrotypographer could generate proportionally-spaced fonts if they really had nothing better to do ...

Comment: @scruss Plus I was a little surprised to see (but confirmed from the MX-80 manual - both the description there (9x9) and the actual font sample which shows an interesting format - a 5 (horizontal) x 9 (vertical) grid, with the horizontal both in the boxes (5) and on the lines between the boxes (another 4). Which means that *both* dimensions were 9, so it wouldn't fit easily in a standard x8-bit ROM. I don't know whether they (and "they" is multiple companies, so each might pick a different method) went with x12, x16 or a packed 9x9=81 -> 11 bytes, or even (yes, wacky) some scheme where

Comment: a particular possible location (e.g., in the 2 descender rows which are less used) skips a bit in order to pack down to 80 bits = 10 bytes. Only practical way to tell is to look at the ROM image.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: The Star Gemini 10x stored each character as 64 bits, with 63 bits being the location of dots in a 9x7 matrix (no descenders), and the last bit being used as an indicator to shift everything down two rows.  A consequence of this is that the "j" places the dot on the same row as the top of the "p", though when I designed my own alternative font, I used a "j" without a dot instead.  I wouldn't be surprised if printers that don't allow uploadable character sets do something similar, but with some special-case logic to handle the "j" so the dot can appear higher.

Comment: BTW, the font sample in the CTI-CP80 ad may not be clear enough to place all dots with pixel-perfect accuracy, and manufacturers may have tweaked fonts between manufacturing runs of some printers, but the Q and j in the ad's print sample definitely do not match the samples from the original poster.

Comment: @supercat Interesting. Looking at the MX-80 manual, they have two characters with descenders that also have something in the top two rows - j, as expected, and a Danish 0x7c ø

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact remember that the characters are stored by column, since that's how the pins fire. So at most, you'd need 9 bits. The ROM I'm most familiar with uses a leading status byte (1 bit descender flag, 3 bits each left/right character bearing for proportional spacing) followed by 11 bytes of column data.

Answer (score 9):

A useful place to start with the matrix dimensions is this diagram from the [Epson LX-810 LX-850 Service Manual](https://archive.org/details/printermanual-epson-lx-810-lx-850-service-manual/page/n10/mode/1up):

[image: 9-pin print head dimensions: each pin is 0.29 mm diameter, and pins are spaced 0.35 mm apart]

Each pin is 0.29 mm diameter, and pins are spaced 0.35 mm apart vertically. Horizontally, the standard step distance was 0.21 mm. As others have said, because of physical limitations in the pin mechanics, horizontally-adjacent dots must be two steps apart, or 0.42 mm. These dimensions are likely common to most 9-pin printers, although one manufacturer I seem to remember used square pins.

If you build your font based on this, you'll get a theoretically accurate model of the device. Practically, however, impact printers suffered from **dot gain**: the physical dots tend to be much larger than the theoretical resolution. This dot gain depended on many variables: ribbon ink level, ribbon thickness/flexibility, print head wear, paper thickness setting, actual paper thickness, paper roughness, ink compatibility … At some point, a designer has to compromise/assume some of these values, and thus create an “idealized version that never was”, as Raffzahn put it.

[image: dot matrix letter M from the Epson FX-80 ROM, shown as theoretical dot size and with simulated dot gain]

There doesn't seem to be a ROM dump of the CTI CP-80 of any version on the internet, alas, or even a manual with a good character table available. For the programmatically inclined, Peter Hull's [Effects Eighty](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/effects-eighty/) may be an interesting place to start when creating a dot matrix look-alike. Although the font itself is based on an idealized version of the Epson FX-80, the font includes source to generate itself, and the characters are defined in a fairly intuitive way:

```
 ...
    "Q":
"""
............
............
............
.*.*.*.*....
*.......*...
*.......*...
*.......*...
*...*...*...
*.....*.....
.*.*.*..*...
............
............
""",
 ...
```

The font matrix looks the same as Epson printers. Here's the SQ-80 sample, with a slightly rescaled outline of Effects Eight overlaid. Plus or minus variations within the range of ink smearing and pin impression variation, they are the same data:

[image: Effects Eighty overlaid on source image]

Comment: thank you SO much for the "ideal" M. That was all I needed to check that my original dot was the right size, as well as to confirm the positioning of the dots horizontally. I think I'm almost there! Since I can't seem to post images in this comment, I will see if I can add 3 more images of my font in progress in the above post. I have "idealized" the font a little as I just can't "do" the bad letter spacing to that extent! I won't be adding hundreds of kerning pairs, but some of the obvious letters (like i, f, j, etc.) will be narrower than M, S, E, etc.

Comment: Re: Effects Eighty - the download includes the Glyphs app source file which is the same app I'm using. His pin dots are much larger (they overlap) and it seems to be a more condensed font compared to the printouts I have. But interesting to poke around in!

Comment: @QuinGold - yes, I'm not sure where the Effects Eighty author got those proportions from, but they don't seem to match anything real. You question has prompted me to finally finish an NLQ dot matrix font I started working on over five years ago, and the printout's been taunting me on my desk since then.

Comment: The world needs more accurate dot matrix fonts, that's for sure! One nice thing is that the character set is pretty limited, and no one expects thousands of kerning pairs. I'm using Glyphs 3, and there is one dot that is saved as a _part and then used in all the glyphs. That means that if I change the size or shape of that source dot, I can make variations very easily. Since my dot matrix printouts are love letters across two continents, maybe I'll make one with a heart-shaped dot!

Comment: I had to google NLQ (Near Letter Quality). There are some interesting links below this wiki article to old magazines. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_letter-quality_printing

Comment: @QuinGold - heart-shaped dot, you say? Like this: [LoveMatrix](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/lovematrix)? It's a seasonally-adjusted version of my [mnicmp](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/mnicmp) 7-pin DECwriter II-inspired font family

Comment: I guess there is nothing new under the sun! Thanks for sharing. I guess I will focus then on dot matrix fonts that look they were were printed with wonky offsets!

Answer (score 3):

This a CP80 which I imported from Japan when I owned Micro Peripherals (Micro P). We distributed it throughout Europe. The quality was not very good so we stopped selling after only a few months.

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, let's eliminate some of the more common printers based on physical layout. I note that there doesn't appear to be any label on the front, where most printers would have one, but there appears to be a small one just above the buttons on the right. We also can't see either side of the printer where the paper knob would be, which would normally be helpful.

What we can see are a couple of details that seem useful:

1. three operating buttons on the right, seemingly in chicklet style
2. a metal paper "tray", which was not used by later printers
3. the buttons are in an insert area and there is a "step" just to the left on the front which appears to be part of the holder for the top cover, which has been removed (and almost certainly has the logo!)

So based on this...

It's not any Centronics that I'm familiar with, they just look different. They were generally not in use by this point anyway as lower-cost companies entered the field.

It's not any of the more common Japanese names like Panasonic or Toshiba, they generally looked like Centronics.

It may be one of the many 9-pin Epson models. They mostly had three buttons on the right, as seen here, and generally in a slightly lowered section, as seen here. Most examples will have white plastic buttons, but I know they made some with dark grey chicklets as seen here. Most notable is the metal paper "tray" at the back, which does indeed seem similar to the Epson from the MX on. However, Epson always had a large metal label on the front on the left, which I do not see here, but it's possible it's just hidden. We also can't see the right side where Epson always had its paper knob. Finally, the covers on Epson normally sat in an indent, so the lip on the front here seems wrong.

So this is pushing me in the direction of one of the many Epson clones.

Judging by the style and placement of the buttons and the metal paper "basket" at the back, this may be a Star Micronics SG or gemini series, in particular, the [gemini-10X](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102622175). However, the Star always had a logo on the front right, which is missing, although it's possible the UK versions were whitelabled. The other issue is that the buttons in the image above are inset, [while the geminis I know are flush with the top](https://www.reddit.com/r/vintagecomputing/comments/wlglsl/just_got_this_star_gemini10x_dot_matrix_printer/). I know there were some differences between models, including ones using white buttons and other minor differences. Unfortunately, I can't find any sample output to compare, although perhaps someone with better eyes than mine can find [something useful here](https://colorcomputerarchive.com/repo/Documents/Manuals/Hardware/Gemini-10x%20&%20Gemini-15x%20(Star%20Mfg.%20Co.).pdf).

My feeling is that it is likely a model from the 1983 through 1986 time-frame, because after that you generally have sheet feeders instead of roll feeders. For instance, compare with the [Star LC-100](https://www.wtsretro.dk/shop/commodore-amiga/commodore/commodore-hardware/star-lc-100-dot-matrix-printer/) and similar models of the later 1980s.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry that this is the only pic I have. It was also of a co-worker so I am assuming that we both had the same model. Being an Epson clone will have to do for now!

Comment: Minor, but if it’s an Epson clone beyond reasonable legal constraints then check out the Epson FX-80 manual for the entire font laid out in large on a grid in the appendix. Sadly I can’t immediately find a copy online that isn’t behind one of those awful online manuals sites, with watermarks, terrible navigation and an entreaty to pay if you just want the PDF.

Comment: @Tommy - Thanks. Someone above included a link to the Epson MX-80 printer manual and it has an Appendix with the Character Grid. This Regular font would be so easy to do in Glyphs as the grid is the same width and height. I've done a wider spaced version to match my printouts, but the Regular grid is a good check and starting point for the symbols I have yet to add.

Comment: @Tommy Epson's own website has a link to FX-80 user manual: https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/fx80__/fx80__u1.pdf

Comment: And the FX-80 specifications from Epson:
http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/fx80__/fx80__sl.pdf